# How to merge or group dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe likes

```
   City    Age   column1  column2
0  Texas   20     7        5
1  Texas   35     8        1
2  Texas   30     8        2
```

I want to merge the column City with same city into 1 row and centralized, other columns are unchanged. So the output like

```
   City    Age   column1  column2
0          20     7        5
1  Texas   35     8        1
2          30     8        2
```

Is it posible to do it with dataframe on pandas. The final target is that I want to save the dataframe to csv file likes

[image]

Comment: The result you want isn't a csv. Its a multilevel table. A csv would include "Texas" as the city column in reach row.

Comment: Is possible to merge it before dump to csv

Answer (score 1):

use pd.merge(df1,df2, how="choose one from inner,left,right, full joins",
onleft = "df1 column name " ,onright = "df2 column name " )